# How to call rest api from winform, shutdown the computer and the call still alive?

Tags: c#, winforms, api, rest

I have the following structure:

- Rest Api in c# (api.com/DoSomethingLazy/) (this take about 10min)
- Winform

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Call rest api method 
  }
  ```

It is possible to turn off the computer and the api method to continue running on server?
Async Method? WebSockets?

Comment: In the REST api launch a new thread to do the work and finish the request after starting that new thread, in the client wait to the request being finished and then shut down the computer.

Comment: @Gusman It is not that easy due to AppDomain Recycling on IIS (the thing that is most likely hosting a REST web service) For a 10 minute background task you are very likely going to have your server side code force terminated before it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your task takes 10 min to do some of the "Easy" ways to queue background work (using [`QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx)) won't work because they will not keep IIS alive long enough (it has a default time limit of 90 seconds).

Your remaining options are:

1. Use a external service - Have a 2nd program that runs as a service on the machine, your IIS site talks to the service and the service is what does the long running operation.
2. Use WebJobs to queue up work - This only works for Azure sites unless you run the WebJob service (but then you are just doing option #1).
3. Use a 3rd party library that acts like WebJobs - Personally I like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/)

All of these solutions are server side options, the WinForm app running on the client does not matter and can't solve the problem. There is no client side fix for this problem.

Comment: The 1 option seems to me the best way. Thank you!